# Spark job success but with ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver disassociated

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

My spark version is 1.6.2 and runs on yarn.

The log of drive container reports `SUCCEEDED` as follows:

```
16/11/17 17:25:56 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: SUCCEEDED, exitCode: 0
16/11/17 17:25:56 INFO ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with SUCCEEDED
```

However, The log of one executor container records an `ERROR`:

```
16/11/17 17:25:56 WARN CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: An unknown (xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:xxxx) driver disconnected.
16/11/17 17:25:56 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:xxxx disassociated! Shutting down.
```

I think the job is succeeded because the output results are as expected.

But I want to know why the error was thrown and whether the job was really succeeded.

I find more info from the log of yarn NodeManager:

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_xxxxxxxxx and exit code: 1
ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Someone encounter the same question?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I want to know why the error was thrown and whether the job was really succeeded.

Comment: Someone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: I think this is due to the bug of spark 1.6.2 in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17696.